# how to read MS Access database in c# datatable

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to read a table from ms access using c#.net and want to store it in a datatable.

when i display the Row from datatable in Combobox, it is not giving the required text.

for eg: it is giving System.Data.DataRow instead of the actual value in the table.

my code:

```
// Global Variables 

    OleDbConnection dbCon = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbDataAdapter dbAdapter;
    DataTable localDT = new DataTable();
    int rowPos;
    int rowNum;

private void ConnectToDb()
    {
        dbCon.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CuttingParameters.mdb";

        try
        {
            dbCon.Open();

            dbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select Distinct Material from CutParameters", dbCon);

            dbAdapter.Fill(localDT);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
        if (localDT.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            rowPos = localDT.Rows.Count;
        }

        textBox1.Text = rowPos.ToString();
    }

    private void FillMatCombo()
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource=localDT;

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ComboBox data binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585243/combobox-data-binding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the **DisplayMember** property of the ComboBox to tell it which property to use as the display label. There is also a **ValueMember** property for which property to use as the value.